# Numerical method to solve a non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, nonlinear-analysis

I want to solve numerically the following non-linear ordinary differential equation:
$$f''(x)=A(1+f'(x)^2)^{3/2}-\frac{f'(x)}{x}(1+f'(x)^2)$$
where $A$ is a constant and $x\in[0,R]$. The ODE is also subjected to the following boundary conditions:
$$f'(0)=0$$
$$f(R)=0$$
My struggle is with what method should I adopt to approximate the solution due to its high non-linearity. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If instead it was a Dirichlet BVP with $f(0) = a$ (instead of $f'(0)$), how would you solve it? I ask because it seemed like you found this aspect of the problem (rather than its extreme nonlinearity!) to be the most troubling part.

Comment: With $f''(0)=\frac{A}{2}$ you get $f(h)=f(0)+\frac{A}{4}h^2$, $f'(h)=\frac{A}{2}h$ for sufficiently small $h$. With that approximation you can solve a regular BVP on $[h,R]$.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong, I would transform it on a system of two first order ODEs and solve it by some method (to be honest I only dealt with IVP up to now, but I think it shouldn't be a problem).

Comment: @LutzLehmann Could you explain to me where that assumption for $f''(0)$ came from (or recommend some reference)? Is it a method or just an arbitrary assumption? Thank you

Comment: @MateusForcelini Well, if you know a good nonlinear solver for the Dirichlet BVP, I would think that would be almost the entire way to solving this mixed BVP, as the nonlinearity appears to be the hardest aspect of this problem.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong Actually I don't know, I'm new to numerical methods for BVPs so any help or reference provided would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For a fully arbitrary nonlinearity, there's not much better one can do than a standard discretization (finite differences or finite elements) and then using Newton method to solve the nonlinear system. Due to the structure of your equations it's always possible you can transform the problem that can be solved in a better way, but for the brute force approach, you can google 'solving nonlinear BVPs' and you should get some examples.

Comment: Can you give typical values of $A$ and $R$? With $A=3$ I get vertical slopes shortly after $x=0.65$.

Comment: With smaller $A$ one can take larger values for $R$. // As $\frac{f'(x)}{x}=\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x-0}\to f''(0)$ for $x\to 0$, one gets in the limit of the equation $2f''(0)=A$. // As $f$ does not appear in the equation, all solutions are vertically shifted copies of each other. So just integrate over $[h,R]$ with initial values $[f(h),f'(h)]=[f_0+Ah^2/4,Ah/2]$ first with $f_0=0$ and then subtract the last value from the curve.

Comment: @LutzLehmann $A$ and $R$ are usually smaller than $1$.  Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong You are right, I couldn't handle the non-linearity very well. I tried a finite difference scheme, but I couldn't form the matrix of the coefficients because of the terms raised to the 3/2 power. I was able to solve it using the Maple software but I need to implement it on a program. Do you have any advice? Thank you!

Comment: Perturbation theory can also work well. If you put $f' = \sinh(u)$, then you have: $$\frac{du}{dx} = A \cosh^2(u) - \frac{\sinh(u)\cosh(u)}{x}$$ If it were not for the second term, you would be able to solve the diff. eq. exactly. You can do a perturbative expansion by multiplying the second term by $\epsilon$ and expanding on powers of $\epsilon$. The zeroth order solution is $u_0(x) = \operatorname{acrtanh}(A x) + c$. It's not difficult to evaluate the higher order terms. If you write down the series, you usually have to resum it using e.g. Padé approximants and then put $\epsilon = 1$.

Comment: @MateusForcelini The nonlinearity just means there is a nonlinear system of algebraic equations to be solved after discretization, which is still a thing that can be done. Indeed you could do it with standard software such as Matlab's bvp4c or bvp5c. The only thing that makes such standard software likely to choke on your problem is the removable singularity in the equation at $x=0$ (which is removable because actually $f'(x)$ is on the order of $x$ as a result of the regularity and the boundary condition). This can be removed by something like what Lutz Lehmann suggested.

Answer (score 1):

So, I adopted a finite difference approximation with a Newton-Rapson scheme to solve the non-linear system and it worked just fine. The singularity at $x=0$ ended up not being a problem since my system of nonlinear equations was:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lcr}
f_2-f_1 = 0 \\
\frac{f_{i+1}-2f_{i}+f_{i-1}}{h^2} - \frac{\gamma}{C}\left(\frac{f_{i+1}^2 -2f_{i+1}f_{i-1}+f_{i-1}^2+4h^2}{4h^2}\right)^{3/2} + \frac{\left(f_{i+1}-f_{i-1}\right)\left(f_{i+1}^2 -2f_{i+1}f_{i-1}+f_{i-1}^2+4h^2\right)}{8h^4(i-1)}\quad\forall 2 \le i\le N-1\\
f_N=0
\end{array}\right.
$$
Thank you all for the replies!